# How is output encoded for YOLO

Tags: conv-neural-network, yolo

If multiple boxes in a grid have same object lets say car, then for all the boxes, that has the car are **bx**, **by**, **bh**, **bw** are the same? Here **bx, by** are the center pixel of the car and **bh, bw** are the height and width of the bounding box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same confusion. Let me give you intuition behind this, how it deal with this problem.

In yolo, we have three important parameters **IOU**, **class-confidence-score** and **box-confidence-score**, which decide, which grid has more probability in all aspect and prune other lower probable grids.

So, even if there are many grids with the same bounding box dimensions, but the **probability of object** in the grid cell is varying, which change the **box confidence score** for the grids, which is calculated as `pr(object).IOU`. This way, yolo remove those grids.

Here is [link](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088), which have detained explanation of yolo.